# can anyone give me a function on the integer defined as $f_{n}(f_{n}(x))=x$ please?

Tags: functions, arithmetic, integers, cryptography

I need a function $f_{n}$ wich for all integer n is an Involution on the integer.

Put in another way I need a function $f_{n}$ so that $f_{n}(f_{n}(x))=x$ for all integer x and n)

ps: And wich is as much as possible is "different" when given different n since this function is supposed to be used with x corresponding to a character to encode and n a corresponding to a character of the key.

Comment: Here is a smaller example from which you can try to build larger examples:  $f_n(x)=\begin{cases} n&\text{if}~x=1\\1&\text{if}~x=n\\x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.  If you were to think of $f_n$ as a "permutation" on the integers (*ignoring the requirement that permutations are ordinarily only from a finite set to itself*), in the disjoint cyclic representation the only appearing cycles would be of length $2$ for every $n$.  The above would be represented in disjoint cyclic representation as $(1~n)$.

Comment: actually i started by using a pseudo random algorithm to randomly shuffle the integer in the range i needed and using n as a seed but I prefer using a well defined function because storing shuffled list require a lot of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classical example is $f_n(x) = x \oplus n$ where $\oplus$ is the binary XOR.

Comment: oh and as it turned out the xor operator even fill a implicit condition i didn't mentioned :if i apply a function to two integer representing character and the result is greater than both integer i may have a result too big to be represented as a character and applying a modulo may broke the involutional property of the function. But in this case if i apply the xor operator to each bit represeneting two number the resulting number has to be smaller than both number. Great solution thanks ! ironicly i thinked of that first but i turned away from it since i wanted to keep my character as integer

Answer (score 1):

I dont not have enough reputations to do this request like a comment

I am not sure but what do you think about $f_n(x)=(-1)^nx $

Answer (score 1):

How about $f_n(x)$ splits the integers into intervals of length $n$ and reverses each interval, i.e.
$$
f_1(x) = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...\\
f_2(x) = 2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9,...\\
f_3(x) = 3,2,1,6,5,4,9,8,7,12...\\
f_4(x) = 4,3,2,1,8,7,6,5,12,11,...\\
f_5(x) = 5,4,3,2,1,10,9,8,7,6,...
$$
and so on.